# The class of finite groups (models) and that of countable groups are not elementary classes (a generalized version).

Tags: logic, model-theory

First some definitions: For a set $\Sigma$ of $\mathcal{L}$-sentences, $Mod(\Sigma)$ denotes the class of all models that satisfy $\Sigma$. For a class $\mathcal{M}$ of models, we say it is $EC$ if $\mathcal{M} = Mod(\sigma)$ for some sentence $\sigma$ and $EC_\Delta$ if $\mathcal{M} = Mod(\Sigma)$.

Problem.
Let $T$ be a theory having arbitrary large finite models. (For example, $T$ can be axioms for groups, or fields, or linear orderings.) Let $\mathcal{K}_{inf} = \{ M : M \models T, \mbox{Card}(|M|)\geq \infty \}$ and $\mathcal{K}_{fin} = \{ M : M \models T, \mbox{Card}(|M|)< \infty \}$.

Question.

(a) What does it mean by 'finite models'? Model's universe finite? Or a finite number of models?

(b) $\mathcal{K}_{inf}$ is $EC_\Delta$

(c) $\mathcal{K}_{fin}$ is $EC_\Delta$

(d)  $\mathcal{K}_{inf}$ is $EC$

Obviously I don't want some full detailed solution. It's just I can't even start on the problems.

Give some suggestions and hints. Should I use Compactness Theorem?

Comment: For (a) it means models with a finite universe.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here are some hints:

b) Can you express "the domain of M is infinite" as a first order theory? Call this theory $\text{Th}(\infty)$. Then the class of models of $T\cup \text{Th}(\infty)$ is $\mathcal{K}_{\text{inf}}$.

c) Here you can use compactness. Suppose $\mathcal{K}_{\text{fin}}$ is the class of models of $T^*$. Then $T^*\cup \text{Th}(\infty)$ is inconsistent. Do you see a problem here?

d) Use part c): if you had a single sentence picking out $\mathcal{K}_{\text{inf}}$, you could find a theory picking out $\mathcal{K}_{\text{fin}}$.